# how to add google sign in and authentication on ember js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-oauth, handlebars.js, google-signin

I am trying to build an ember app which needs to authenticate and allow people with their email using google sign in... I referred documentations but almost all used torii as bearer service and ember-simple-auth as session manager. The problem is torii havent had a patch since 2018 and is failing to work with ember current version thus couldnt proceed on with the project.. so how to add google sign in and authenticate functionality in my ember without that?
also i couldnt retrive aany information of the signed in user with the following code.. I added the client id and js  from google api in my index.html and added the basic sign in button but dont know how to retrive information from it..

my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Signin</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="93818-913ria6b3vcjh2.apps.googleusercontent.com">//---->client id
    {{content-for "head"}}

    <link integrity="" rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.css">
    <link integrity="" rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/signin.css">

    {{content-for "head-footer"}}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{content-for "body"}}
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>//---->google api js script
    <script src="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="{{rootURL}}assets/signin.js"></script>

    {{content-for "body-footer"}}
  </body>
</html>
```

my handlebar code

```
<h2><center>Sign in using google</center></h2>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the traditional answer has been an addon called torii. Unfortunately, the official version of torii hasn't been updated in a few years. But you can use this fork today:

https://github.com/adopted-ember-addons/torii

Use it in your package.json like this: `"torii": "adopted-ember-addons/torii#79205147215a56b6b0a99745eaf9844d44744085"

I hope it can get published on npm soon.

It is compatible with ember-simple-auth 4.2.2.